# Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock

Tags: github, docker-image

I am trying to connect to a docker image, for that, i tried those commands:

```
export CR_PAT=<your token access>
echo $CR_PAT | docker login ghcr.io --password-stdin -u <your username>
```

I used as username my Github username and as result, i got:

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at 
unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/auth": 
dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

so to fix it, i tried to give permissions for all users using the following command:

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
```

and when i retype

```
    echo $CR_PAT | docker login ghcr.io --password-stdin -u <your username>
```

the terminal didn't return any answer!! it's blocked ..

any help please??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by restarting the computer.

Comment: I have encountered the same issue and restarting did not solve the problem.

Comment: @JerodG I think you have to pay attention to your personal access token rights. create another token and retype commands !